# How to implement an abstract getter with property

Tags: kotlin

I have java code:

```
public abstract class A {
   abstract int getA()
}
```

I tried:

```
class B : A() {
    val a = 0
}
```

Doesn't compile.

```
class B : A() {
    override val a = 0
}
```

Still doesn't compile.

```
class B : A() {
    override val a: Int get () = 1
}
```

Still doesn't compile.

```
class B : A() {
    override val a: Int override get () = 1
}
```

Still doesn't compile.

```
class B : A() {
    val a: Int override get () = 1
}
```

None of them are working. Does that mean I can only use

```
class B : A() {
    override fun getA() = 1
}
```

? I think the last one(overriding the method) is ugly.

This could be worse when you have a getter-setter pair. It's expected to override getter-setter pair with a `var` property, but you have to write two methods.

Comment: `override val a = 0` should work. What's the error message?

Comment: [please see image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16398479/27009722-ec3dfd00-4e5a-11e7-8adf-cdb46995efb0.png)
P.S. I promise they're in the same package, because `override fun getA() = 1` works.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I just checked it myself. The error is "'A' overrides nothing", which seems weird, given that it should compile a method with the exact same name (`getA`).

Comment: @GiantTree please read the last few lines of the question again.

Comment: You can override a property with a property, e. g. `interface A { val x: Type }` `class B(override val x: Type) : A`. Function can be overridden only with a function.

Comment: @Miha_x64 that's a pity. Thanks.

Comment: If it's "ugly" in the sense that you are now required to use it as a function, you may consider creating a val of a different name and overriding getA to call that val's getter. It's still ugly but it will make other calls nicer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to @Miha_x64 ,

> functions can be overriden only with a function.

Seems that I was trying something impossible.